# When powering a Nrf24L01 hooked up to an arduino by external battery does ground still go to the Arduino ground?

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, radio

So as mentioned in this article, the radio chip might have power problems and an external power source is recommended:

http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo

My question is for the ground connection, Should I connect this to the ground pin of the Arduino board?  Or, since the power is seperate from the Arduino, does the GND and VCC go to the black and red external leads of the battery directly ?

[image: chip]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GND of the battery and the Arduino shoud be anyway connected together so it does not matter. 
Connect it that way and the Arduino to the battery (Vcc to 3.3V the data-pins are 5V tolerant):
[image]

An example pin-connection would be (but this depends on your code):

[image: An example pin-connection woud be:]

For the Nano this might help:

[image: connection for arduino nano]

Comment: I'm confused why you hooked some up to the ICSP pins which appear to be for flashing?

Comment: @stormist: Those are the SPI pins which, while also used for ISP, are used for SPI communication.

Comment: So in this example, it is optional to use them correct? I could elect to use standard digital pins right? (I ask because I'm using the Arduino Nano) Thx!

Comment: You *could* bit-bang SPI if you *really* wanted to. But it would be faster to use hardware SPI instead.

Comment: @stormist yes you can it depends on your code. I posted a standard pin connection to my answer.

Comment: I'm using this code: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=138663.0

Comment: Here you have got a project with the Nrf and a Arduino Nano: [link](http://hack.lenotta.com/arduino-raspberry-pi-switching-light-with-nrf24l01/)

Comment: @stormist: Turns out that pins 10-13 *are* the SPI pins, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ground is used as a reference for the voltages on the SPI pins; if separate grounds are used then these voltages will not be able to be detected properly and communication between the Arduino and the wireless board will fail. Connect the grounds.